# Add a link href with css content

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I need to set an url after the class `module-content`, with pure css. This code doesn't work, but basically i need to set the `Custom‌·Link` in the `content: ' ' attr(href);`.

```html
<div class="module-content">
   <div class="aidanews2" style="clear: both;">
      <div class="aidanews2_art aidacat_2 aidapage105 hidepiece odd first" style="clear: both; display: block;">
      <div class="aidanews2_art aidacat_2 aidapage105 hidepiece even last" style="clear: both; display: block;">
   </div>
   <div class="aidanews2_bottomlink">
      <a href="/joomla/index.php">Custom‌·Link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```css
.moduletable>.module-content:after{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #050505;
    content: ' ' attr(href);
}
```

unsuccessful **Jquery** attempt:

```js
var a = $('.aidanews2_bottomlink').html();
var b = $('.top-1 > .moduletable > .module-content:after ').html(a);
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what exactly you're trying to do - your description is unclear to me.

Comment: So you need to replace `Custom‌·Link` with `/joomla/index.php` ?

Comment: Does this need to be done using CSS?  It's a little unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but this feels like something that would be much simpler using JavaScript instead.

Comment: No, @Musa i just want to insert the url link of aidanews2_bottomlink after the .module-content.

Comment: @aroth could be JS, my attempt failed (Jquery).

Comment: JavaScript/jQuery cannot access html pseudo elements.

Comment: Is this roughly what you're after?  http://jsfiddle.net/ANZgE/

Comment: @aroth thanks, but definitely not the solution that i am looking for. A bit strange that there is no way of add a link to a pseudo element :after.

Comment: Perhaps [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ANZgE/2/), then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/whCF3/

Comment: @aroth, if you add your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps more easily done using JavaScript/jQuery.  That would be how I'd approach it, anyways.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to 1) fetch the `href` attribute on the link and 2) output it as text after the closing tag on the enclosing `module-content` div.

That can be accomplished with the following code:

```
//get the text
var content = $(".aidanews2_bottomlink a").attr('href');  

//append it after the containing element
$(".aidanews2_bottomlink").parents(".module-content").eq(0).after(content);
```

Here's a live example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ANZgE/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is what your HTML and CSS should look like:

```
<div class="module-content" data-href="/joomla/index.php">
   <div class="aidanews2" style="clear: both;">
      <div class="aidanews2_art aidacat_2 aidapage105 hidepiece odd first" style="clear: both; display: block;">
      <div class="aidanews2_art aidacat_2 aidapage105 hidepiece even last" style="clear: both; display: block;">
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.moduletable > .module-content:after{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #050505;
    content: ' ' attr(data-href);
}
```

The line `content: ' ' attr(data-href);` is looking for the attribute `data-href` in the element `.module-content`.